# asp.net mvc3 razor syntax to cast a model to its subclass by reflection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, razor, casting

I have very simple question that I cannot find the answer to.
In the razor view there's a Model of interface type. That interface have multiple subclasses implementing it.
The question is: *How can I cast the model to its actual type*?
I **MUST** have variable of actual type but don't know how to get it from the reflection
I.E.

```
@model IInterface
@{
   var actualType1 = Model as Model.GetType(); // doesn't work :(
   var actualType2 = (Model.GetType()) Model; // doesn't work :(
}
```

As you can imagine I am not interested in `Model as ActualType` or `(ActualType) Model` because I don't know what actual type is coming in advance. Its a question about the technique rather than architecture.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know you mentioned it explicitly, but **why** do you want to have the specific subclass instance? Because that's denying the purpose of working with interfaces and suggests a design smell.

Comment: I have hierarchy of view models that are very similar and the only differences between them is data annotations (labels, validations tooltips etc). So that they all inherit from the same interface and only differ by data annotation on the fields. Unfortunately MVC doesn't go for data annotation and validation by actual class, but by model type defined in your view. To me this is OO violation, and I am looking for workaround this.

Comment: I think you'll find you can do what you want with Editor Templates/Display Templates.  As long as you are using different concrete classes it's all fine - I've found that works perfectly.  Equally, there is no real reason for a View to have to use interfaces exclusively and not concrete types in a closed system.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan agree with you 100% about editor templates. If I used editor templates with concrete classes - they'll work just fine, **problem** with it though is that they'll be exactly the same editor templates. Imagine editor templates folder filled in with 10 different templates which are exactly the same on the inside except the model class. Kinda stupid. This is what I am trying to workaround

Comment: Well, you can use layouts on partial views to give you the commonality there.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan can give more details? Not sure what you mean... Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are really on the wrong path here.  You can't really do what you're looking to do here, because you are not really thinking it through.  A statement like this:

```
var actualType1 = Model as Model.GetType();
```

Won't work because var is not a dynamic type, it's a static type that is typed at compile time, not at runtime.  So even if you could somehow manage to get it to work, it would only work for one type, ever (until it was recompiled again).

In addition to that, interfaces are a poor choice for this, because interface attributes are seperate from implementation attributes.  So regardless of what attributes you have on your classes, you will not get them via an interface to that class.

Comment: If what you saying is accurate (it seems to be) - how do you solve data annotation and validation problem like this? You have same classes (about 10 if them) with different annotations. I keep them in List<MyInterface> and display them in the view one after the other, but I need to get annotations right.

Comment: @DisplayName - You don't.  You can't make this work, at least not out of the box.  It would take rewriting a lot of code to solve it, and it's not really worth it.  Instead of different data annotations, why not use somethign liek FluentValidation instead?

Comment: Unfortunately FluentValidation doesn't take into account DisplayAttribute, which I am after. Can you point me to something that I can use similar to FluentValidation for DisplayAttribute (meaning defining what's displayed including tooltips & placeholders on the fly by actual type rather than by `@model` type? Thanks

Comment: @DisplayName - I don't know what you're trying to do, but it seems like whatever it is, you're going about it the wrong way.  If you just want dynamic labels, why not make them fields in your model and fill them in your business logic, then just use DisplayFor or something to insert them in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have, according to your OP comments, some data annotation problems.  I would highly suggest completely recreating some models and interfaces that use the [MetadataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx).

```
public SomeViewModel
{
  public string FormField { get; set; }
  public string FormField2 { get; set; }
}

public interface IAnonymousSomeViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string FormField { get; set; }
  [Scaffold(false)]
  public string FormField2 { get; set; }
}


public interface IUserSomeViewModel
{
  [Scaffold(false)]
  public string FormField { get; set; }
  [Required]
  public string FormField2 { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IAnonymousSomeVieModel)]
public AnonymousViewModel : SomeViewModel { }


[MetadataType(typeof(IUserSomeVieModel)]
public UserViewModel : SomeViewModel { }
```

In your View you pass either `AnonymousViewModel` or `UserViewModel`, then there is NO logic in the view:

```
@model SomeViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormField)

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FormField2)
```

Comment: In your code, I will get no annotations at all, because model type is actually SomeViewModel, which have no decorations. Unless I am missing something...

Comment: You don't pass in `SomeViewModel`, as I stated you pass in `AnonymousVieModel` or `UserViewModel` in this case.  Since they derive from `SomeViewModel` they are accepted by the view.  When the `Html.EditFor` or `Html.DisplayFor` render a field, they render from the `MetaDataType` descriptor.

Comment: Hi Eric, 
probably my bad, I don't see them deriving `SomeViewModel`. In fact I don't see relationship between `SomeViewModel` and each of `AnonymousViewModel` or `UserViewModel`. If they derived from `SomeViewModel` as you stated, I will need to test it in code and will get back to you. Have you tested it to give you right annotations? 
Thanks.

Comment: You're right, let me update.  Yes this works, [MetadataType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.metadatatypeattribute.aspx) was designed for this exact reason.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Before I test it, gut tells me it won't work, MVC goes by model type which is undecorated. This is exactly the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: If you click on the link for MetadataType which was released in with MVC3 (actually .Net 4.0) it solves this exact problem.

Comment: Hi Eric, unfortunately this doesn't work. Razor **always goes by view model type, rather than by its actual type**. As I said, it looks to me as strict OO violation and I was hoping some mechanism like the one you describe would work. It doesn't. I tried multiple combinations of what you suggested, annotations are **always** as per view accepting model, never by actual type. Hope you have more suggestions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually sorry, it's not always by model type, because you can define view models as Interfaces(@model IInterface), which can't be instantiated.  Beyond that, I actually use @Html.EditorForModel(), and assumed there was no difference between EditorForModel and EditorFor (which there strangely does appear to be a difference).  Let me see why this is happening....

Comment: I tried use not interfaces but (abstract and not abstract) classes - same pattern, no way it goes by actual type, but always by model type declared in the beginning of the page at `@model` level. Trust me I tried so many permutations and combinations, always the same result (defying OO in my opinion).