# Polymorphic MVC Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, polymorphism, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am making a registration page in ASP.NET MVC and theres a list of fields which changes depending on a number of conditions (taken from a database).

What would be considered the best approach for displaying these fields on a view without code changes each time the DB is updated.

The current system I am thinking about is making a Dictionary with "Name, DataType" then just iterating through the list and putting a new input type of each name (using a switch for data type to get the correct editor). But it seems like a old fashioned and not fully utilizing the benefits of the .NET MVC system (such as validation, default values, customized editors for specific content).

Is there a approach I may possibly be not aware of in .NET to handle this problem?

Comment: The best approach (from a MVC perspective) would be to make different Views for each scenarios since "the view should never include any type of logic". However, I doubt this is the type of answer you were seeking for, so I'm not going to post this as an answer. Could you supply additional details on what your are trying to acheive and why? This would help us find a more specific solution to your issue (one that you won't mind applying).

Comment: @Pluc basically its a event registration system, each "Client" specifies their own custom fields which is required for the end user to enter before they are allowed to register. Since we don't control the client entries its difficult for us to make a view for each scenario :(

Comment: So the fields can be of multiple types and any quantity?

Comment: How is that form's fields saved when submited? If the data required is dynamic, then the database has a User -> UserDetail relationship?

Comment: I'm thinking I just grab the list of "data names" from the DB, then scan the form to see if they get input or not. Not 100% sure the best method yet.

Comment: Your question was way too specific. Your idea of what you are trying to do is too vague. You should settle on what exactly your plan is before asking how to "polymorph" views. Your not even sure how your data will be stored yet you are trying to display it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had very similar problem. Posting is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832044/asp-net-mvc3-razor-syntax-to-cast-a-model-to-its-subclass-by-reflection).

No, there is no polymorphism views in ASP.NET MVC. At least I couldn't make it work doing tons and tons of experimentation and asking this question several times in different ways on Stack Overflow.

The type of `@model` defined in the view will define its type inside the view, rather than actual type of the model (in case it was interface or abstract class or base class, while you passing in child class with all your beautiful decorations, which won't work, since type is defined by model type).

Sorry, no positive answer to your question. I ended up writing bunch of editor templates, which were only different by model type inside. Huge DRY violation, but this is the way ASP MVC worked, *unfortunately*.

Hope this helps saving you some time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I can now cease to bang my head against the OO deficient nature of ASP.NET MVC. All my experiments so far confirm exactly what you say: here is no polymorphism views in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: enjoy. it is lots of time spent, so was trying to save a bit of it to others