# cant use Interface in partial as model - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `partial` witch has model like belowe :

```
@model ViewModel.DropdownViewModel.DropdownResultViewModel<ViewModel.BaseViewModel.IDropdownViewModel,dynamic>
```

and `DropdownResultViewModel` like this :

```
 public class DropdownResultViewModel<T, K> 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { get; set; }
    public K SelectedId { get; set; }
    public string ControlId { get; set; }
    public string DefaultText { get; set; }
    public string DataValueField { get; set; }
    public string DataTextField { get; set; }

}
```

and I passed data like this :

```
DropdownResultViewModel<LocationViewModel, Guid> result = new DropdownResultViewModel<LocationViewModel, Guid>();
        result.ControlId = controlId;
        result.Items = _locationService.GetAll();
        result.SelectedId = selectedId.HasValue ? selectedId.Value : Guid.Empty;

        return PartialView(MVC.Shared.Views._LocationDropdown,result);
```

and `LocationViewModel` Like this:

```
public class LocationViewModel:IDropdownViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid? ParentId { get; set; }

}
```

I getting this error :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ViewModel.DropdownViewModel.DropdownResultViewModel'2[ViewModel.Location.LocationViewModel,System.Guid]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ViewModel.DropdownViewModel.DropdownResultViewModel'2[ViewModel.BaseViewModel.IDropdownViewModel,System.Object]'.

how can I do this ?
I searched on the `Net` but cant any Similar problems.

Comment: Make sure the properties you're passing are not null.

Comment: @DCruz22 I checked that , it has some data ,

Comment: maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147167/polymorphic-mvc-views

Comment: Short answer is you can't

Comment: The problem is the variance (which only works for interfaces). You could define an interface `IDropdownResultViewModel<out T, out K>`, but your specific properties would not allow such an interface to be constructed. One solution would be making the model `dynamic` (with `@model dynamic`): you'd lose intellisense and compile-time checking, but it'd definitely work

Comment: look at it with `dynamic`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vz7g28

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you have any similar idea ?

Comment: @Jcl I try with your code , but getting same error ?

Comment: @UthmanRahimi uh, which code?

Answer (score 0):

System.Guid is a struct not an object that's the error.